# Symfony2, transform only <a></a> in link

Tags: html, symfony

I created a form with a textarea.

When I try to put HTML in this `text area`, save my form, and display the new data on my page, I can see all `HTML TAGS`, without interpretation. It's just normal.

But I need to be interpreted all link tags a>/a>, and only this tag....

How can I do that ? Is there an option with `formbuilder` ? 
I need to do something before saving the data ? When I display the data ? Thanks !

Comment: You mean to find all `<a></a>` tags and convert them to real link on the ouput?

Comment: do you need the anchor tags rendered in the form or only when displaying the data?  if you need it only on display just use twig filter raw, if you need it rendered in your from, you're basically going to need a wysiwyg of some sort.

Comment: Using `raw` will render other tags too

Answer (score 0):

You should just create a custom Twig filter:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html